# How does the rsync symlink exploit work?

Tags: security, rsync

> `munge symlinks`
>
> [...]
>
> The  way  rsync  disables the use of symlinks is to prefix each one with the string "/rsyncd-munged/".  This prevents the links from
>                 being used as long as that directory does not exist.  When this parameter is enabled, rsync will refuse to run if  that  path  is  a
>                 directory or a symlink to a directory.
>
> [...]
>
> When this parameter is disabled on a writable module and "use chroot" is off (or the inside-chroot path is not "/"),  incoming  sym‐
>                 links  will  be modified to drop a leading slash and to remove ".." path elements that rsync believes will allow a symlink to escape
>                 the module’s hierarchy.  There are tricky ways to work around this, though, so you had better trust your users if  you  choose  this
>                 combination of parameters.

When `munge symlinks = no`, what is the tricky way to work around the protection described here?  I.e to escape the module path, and read/write files outside of it?

EDIT:  The vulnerability fixed by "munge symlinks" is [CVE-2007-6199](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2007-6199). "rsync before 3.0.0pre6, when running a writable rsync daemon that is not using chroot, allows remote attackers to access restricted files **via unknown vectors** that cause rsync to create a symlink that points outside of the module's hierarchy."

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I assume it would be possible to upload a symbolic link to e.g. `/etc/passwd` or some other arbitrary file on the system, and then get `rsync` to retrieve that file.

Comment: @Kusalananda right. But rsync has a best-effort protection against it. "incoming sym‐ links will be modified to drop a leading slash and to remove ".." path elements that rsync *believes* will allow a symlink to escape the module’s hierarchy". So what's the specific trick to confuse rsync, so that it allows enough ".." to escape?

Comment: I see what you're getting at now. I misread the second paragraph.